# TodoList application android

Tags: java, android

Please I need your help .I'am trying to take the date from an activity and then put it in an array list then print it in an ListView .

The problem is the data that I should take it from "Adding Todo" is not  showing in the ListView . it do take me to the List Activity but without showing the data .

This is How the app going to be "Adding todo"

[image]

And this is the ListView where the data should be in it

[image]

---

My code :-

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    todoAdapter = new  TodoAdapter(this , arrayList);
   listView.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, AddTodo.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, Intent_Constants.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE);
}

protected void  onActivityResult(int reqCode ,int resultCode , Intent data ){
    // here Iam trying to get the data from ADDING TO DO class
    if(resultCode == Intent_Constants.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE){

        titleText = data.getStringExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_TITLE);
        priorityText = data.getStringExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_PRIORITY);
        statusText = data.getStringExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_STATUES);
        dateText = data.getStringExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_DATE);
        timeText = data.getStringExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_TIME);

        todoAdapter.todo.add(new Todo (titleText , statusText ,priorityText ,dateText ,timeText));


    }
}
```

**Intent_Constants**

```
public class Intent_Constants {
    public final static  int INTENT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public final static int INTENT_RESULT_CODE = 1 ;
    public final static String INTENT_TITLE = "Title";
    public final static String INTENT_PRIORITY = "Priority";
    public final static String INTENT_TIME = "Time";
    public final static String INTENT_DATE = "Date";
    public final static String INTENT_STATUES = "Statues";
}
```

**AddTodo class**

In this class I find the id then I converted to String

```
public void saveButton (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_TITLE , title);
    intent.putExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_DATE , date);
    intent.putExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_TIME , time);
    intent.putExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_PRIORITY , priority);
    intent.putExtra(Intent_Constants.INTENT_STATUES , completed);

    setResult(INTENT_RESULT_CODE, intent);

    finish();
 }
```

**TodoAdapter class**

```
ArrayList<Todo> todo ;

public TodoAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Todo> todo) {
   super(context, R.layout.todo_list,todo);
    this.todo = todo;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView titleText;
    TextView priorityText;
    TextView dateText;
    TextView timeText;

    CheckBox statusBox;

    ImageButton edit_image;
    ImageButton open_image;
    ImageButton delet_image;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext()) ;

    View customeView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_list,parent ,false);

    holder.titleText.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
    holder.priorityText.setText(getItem(position).getPriority());
    holder.dateText.setText(getItem(position).getDate());
    holder.timeText.setText(getItem(position).getTime());

    holder.statusBox.setChecked(false);

    holder.edit_image = customeView.findViewById(R.id.edit_imageView);
    holder.open_image = customeView.findViewById(R.id.open_imageButton);
    holder.delet_image = customeView.findViewById(R.id.delete_imageView);

    holder.edit_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_edit_black_24dp);
    holder.open_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_refresh_black_24dp);
    holder.delet_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp);

    return customeView;
}
```

**Todo class**

```
public class Todo {
    private String title ;
    private String status ;
    private String priority ;
    private String date ;
    private String time ;

    public Todo() {
    }

    public Todo(String title, String status, String priority, String date, String time) {
        this.title = title;
        this.status = status;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setPriority(String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Comment: okay but what problem are you facing ?

Comment: that's nice that you try it, but what is your question? you forgot to ask it.

Comment: the data is not printing in the ListView

Comment: did `onActivityResult` get called ?

Comment: it can be typo ...but you missing findViewById of your textview in getview method

Comment: no i did write findViewById and then I converted to String .

Comment: @JohnJoe  onActivityResult maybe that the problem I didn't call it ? How can I do that ?

Comment: @Noura Add Toast in `OnActivityResult`. Does it display anything ?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes it display

Comment: Please complete TodoAdapter class

Comment: @JohnJoe it is complete

Comment: @Noura change this         arrayList.add(new Todo(titleText , statusText ,priorityText ,dateText ,timeText));
to - todoAdapter.arrayList.add(new Todo(titleText , statusText ,priorityText ,dateText ,timeText));

Comment: add `listView.setAdapter(todoAdapter);` after line `arrayList.add(new Todo(titleText , statusText ,priorityText ,dateText ,timeText));`

Comment: @JohnJoe still not showing the data

Answer (score 0):

You can just set a new adapter, I know it isn't best way, but should do the work. Don't create new one, but nulify yours, and initialize it with new data.

Comment: I want to use the adapter that I created

Answer (score 0):

@Noura change this

```
arrayList.add(new Todo(titleText , statusText ,priorityText ,dateText ,timeText));
```

to

```
todoAdapter.todo.add(new Todo(titleText , statusText ,priorityText ,dateText ,timeText));
todoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and at the constructor u need to update your code like below

```
ArrayList<Todo> todo ;

public TodoAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Todo> todo) {
this.todo = todo
super(context, R.layout.todo_list,todo);
}
```

Comment: todoAdapter doesn't have any arraylist object.

Comment: then how the data would be rendered?
what value would be passed to viewHolder? @VivekMishra

Comment: arraylist is defined in the activity class and is passed to the adapter

Comment: yes but at that time the arraylist was empty, and then the data is only added to the arraylist of activity , not to the arraylist which adapter is having , hence we need to pass the data to array list of adapter or else we need to set the list to adapter after adding data

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged is being called, that will notify the adapter that the data is available and will be rendered

Comment: @VivekMishra todoAdapter does have an object of arraylist named todo

Comment: if you are directly updating your adapter's todo list then you don't need to pass that in constructor. Although that is not a good way to do that.

Comment: can u please update your question with latest code chages

Comment: add notifyDataSetChanged() too after adding data in list

Comment: put a debug point at onActivityResult and check weather the data is coming and then after adding it to list check list size of adapter